# Lithium Battery Protection DW01

Tags: batteries, protection, lipo

I'm using DW01 to protect LiPo batteries. But since there are more than one source of voltage in the circuit, I need to add a diode to DW01's VCC pin for the situations that battery is removed and reverse voltage across battery protection circuit causes unwanted behavior.

[image]
The best schottky diode with least forward voltage drop that I have access to is BAT54C. Voltage difference across R1 (100 ohms) is measured 0.15V that indicates 1.5mA through it. Using BAT54C datasheet charts, if I replace R1 resistor with BAT54C I'll have almost 250mV voltage drop across it (@25'C).

[image]

I do not know the function of R1 in the circuit, so I can not tell if replacing it with a schottky diode that has almost same voltage drop will interfere with its functionalities or not.
Please guide me through this. Is R1 replaceable with a schottky diode? Or should I simply add the diode in series with it? Or this theory of mine is impossible all together!

Comment: Do you really mean "reverse voltage"? Explain how this happens because it won't do the battery much good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you shouldn't need any series diode.

Also the IC monitors the battery voltage through its Vcc pin and stops charging/discharging based on the measured voltage. So, putting a series diode will cause the IC to measure a wrong voltage and therefore to change the behaviour of protections.

Instead, you can implement a very simple reverse polarity protection with a MOSFET (a.k.a. MOSFET ideal diode):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpg67K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sup>**NOTE:** M1 can be 2N700x (7000 or 7002).</sup>

When the battery first applied with correct polarity, current will flow through M1's body diode first, so the M1's source voltage will be one diode drop above BAT- level. This makes the Vgs of M1 positive and turns it on. The voltage drop will be minimal. If the battery is applied with reverse polarity then the body diode of M1 will be reverse biased so no current *(except a leakage of a few nA or pA)* will flow.

> I do not know the function of R1 in the circuit ...

R1-C1 pair is there to filter out any potential noise/ripple coming from the supply line to VCC pin.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer and detailed explanation of it's logic. I'll test it as soon as I get my hands on 2N7002 mosfet that I have just ordered. Teşekkürler